# Copy values from one worksheet to another worksheet file

Tags: excel, vba

The first two lines, i have it looping to copy complete sheets over to another file.. Which is fine because i want the formatting but not the links back to the original file it copied from just the values only.  The second part that is commented out works as it will copy the values only.. but i want the formatting copied as it does in the first two lines with the values only.  How can i combine this .. i have looked at other examples and i can't seem to get a working answer. thanks

```
               xlWorksheetSource = xlWorkbookSource.Sheets(sheet.Name)
                xlWorksheetSource.Copy(After:=xlWorkbookDestination.Worksheets(xlWorkbookDestination.Worksheets.Count))


                'xlWorksheetSource.UsedRange.Copy()
                'xlWorkDestSource = xlWorkbookDestination.Worksheets.Add()
                'xlWorkDestSource.UsedRange._PasteSpecial(XlPasteType.xlPasteValues, XlPasteSpecialOperation.xlPasteSpecialOperationNone, False, False)
                'xlWorkDestSource.Name = sheet.Name
```

Answer (score 1):

This will work to paste cell formatting and values:

```
xlWorksheetSource.UsedRange.Copy()
xlWorkDestSource = xlWorkbookDestination.Worksheets.Add()
xlWorkDestSource.Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteAllUsingSourceTheme
xlWorkDestSource.Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
```

If you only need values and number formatting you can do this:

```
xlWorksheetSource.UsedRange.Copy()
xlWorkDestSource = xlWorkbookDestination.Worksheets.Add()
xlWorkDestSource.Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
```

**Update**

To work with merged cells this will work. *There may be a better / faster way*

```
xlWorksheetSource = xlWorkbookSource.Sheets(sheet.Name)
                xlWorksheetSource.Copy(After:=xlWorkbookDestination.Worksheets(xlWorkbookDestination.Worksheets.Count))

xlWorkDestSource = xlWorkbookDestination.Worksheets(xlWorkbookDestination.Worksheets.Count)

For each cel in xlWorkDestSource.UsedRange
    cel.MergeArea.Value = cel.MergeArea.Value
Next
```

*Please note that I didn't qualify any of the objects, because you didn't in your code, but its definitely a best practice.

Comment: i tried the first one and i get an error "This operation requires the merged cells to be identically sized"

Comment: @Sirus - that is whole different problem. It would have been useful to know you had merged cells to begin with. I suggest getting rid of the merged cells first. (If it's for formatting, try using `CenterAcrossSelection` in the formatting for two (or more) cells across a column).

Comment: i can't change the original spreadsheets.. they are formatted that way and cannot be changed

Comment: ok thanks for helping... i get an error on the line where you set range(cel.mergearea.address).value etc etc.  what do i set range as?  otherwise i get object not set to instance of an object...

Comment: @sirus - try with that edit, mine worked the other way as well

Comment: ok just trying and getting an Public member 'Value' on type 'String' not found. error now on that line.. trying to figure it out

Comment: hard to help more without seeing the data itself @sirus

Comment: sorry i forgot to remove the address part in that line... it loops through now but eventually crashes causing a HRESULT 0x800401A8.  i have to stop it... basically get a run time error 9, subscript out of range when i open the excel sheet after..